# Java Spring Boot Security Class Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

My aim is to add security class to my Java project except paths like "**api/public/***".

When I request in POSTMAN

```
http://localhost:8080/api/public/signup
```

with a json body, I get 401. Here's my security class which permits all matchers of api/public/*:

What am I missing?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            // don't create session
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil);
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // disable page caching
    httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
            .cacheControl();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mvn clean solved my problem. It seems build somehow stuck in a previous state.

```
mvn clean
```